# How to run a single test in scalatest from maven

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I have not found any documentation on how to do this. For JUnit the equivalent would be:

```
mvn -Dtest=org.apache.spark.streaming.InputStreamSuite test
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**tl;dr** `mvn test -Dsuites="some.package.SpecsClass"`

---

I found an answer from here and it works:(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/Rr0gy61dg-0)

run test 'a pending test' in `HelloSuite`, and all tests in `HelloWordSpec`:

```
 mvn test -Dsuites='org.example.
HelloSuite @a pending test, org.example.HelloWordSpec'
```

- run all tests in `HelloSuite` containing `'hello'`:

  `mvn test` `-Dsuites='org.example.HelloSuite` `hello'`

for more details: http://scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin

Comment: I can’t get this to work. Maven keeps complaining that ‘a pending test’ is an unknown lifecycle.

Comment: It does not work at all, Maven still discover all suites.

Comment: @ideck you may have written `-Dsuites 'org.example...'` instead of `-Dsuites='org.example...'` ?

Answer (score 23):

Found the answer: it is

```
-DwildcardSuites
```

So here is the example command line:

```
mvn -pl streaming -DwildcardSuites=org.apache.spark.streaming.InputStreamSuite test
```

**Update**  Newer versions of `scalatest` use

```
 -Dsuites
```

So the syntax would be:

```
mvn -pl streaming -Dsuites=org.apache.spark.streaming.InputStreamSuite test
```

Answer (score 18):

Note that if you have some Java tests in the same module, as much of spark does, you need to turn them off -which you can do by telling surefire to run a test that isn't there

Here is the test that I've just been running

```
mvn test -Dtest=moo -DwildcardSuites=org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientSuite
```

That skips the java test and only runs the scala one.

One thing which scalatest doesn't seem to do is let you run a single test within a suite, the way maven surefire does. That's not ideal if you have one failing test in a big suite.

[**Correction 2016-08-22**: looks like you can ask for a specific suite by name; look at the other answers below. Happy to be wrong].